# Can I set an Event Attendee to act as a Host (e.g. admit external guests) for Google Calendar events via the API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm programmatically creating events in a central account calendar (this is a requirement by my client) using the Google Calendar API. Then I'm adding the external guests to the event, also using the API.

When the event time arrives, the central account is not the one that is being used to host the event; there is a real person who is a host for the event. This is a problem because this real person must be able to admit other guests when they try to join the event (right now only the host can accept other guests).

When you are invited to a Google event and you are not in the same workspace (or don't have a Google account) you need to wait to be admitted as a guest by the host.

I've been checking the API documentation, but the only alternative I was able to find was to move the event to the "real host" attendee's calendar, but for that that attendee will need to share their calendar with my central account. That is not desired, because I can have different persons that will need this permission (basically it's decided per event).

Is there any other possible solution to this problem that will let me create the event using the Google calendar API **and** give "host" permissions to one of the guests so that they can admit other guests into the Google meeting room?

Whatever solution I go with should be implemented during event creation using the API, ideally. At the time the event is created using the API, I want to assign permissions to one guest to act as a Host.